# UISwitch performing action on value change-iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, nsmutablearray, uiswitch

I have a `UISwitch` and I need to load the value in a string into an array when change the switch state change to OFF to ON. I have used the following code, but not working.

```
-(IBAction)toggleSwitch1:(id)sender {
    if (addSwitch.on) {
        [addSwitch addTarget:self action:@selector(addName:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
        NSLog(@"%@",userName);
    }else {
        NSLog(@"No");
    }
}

-(void)addName:(UIControl*)sender {
    [alertList addObject:userName];
    NSLog(@"AlertList: %@", alertList);
}
```

And if once the state changed to ON, how can I remain the same state, if I reload the page?

Please share your thoughts. 
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `viewDidLoad` use this one:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad 
{
    [super viewDidLoad];    
    NSUserDefaults *userdefault=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    if([userdefault boolForKey:@"yes"]) {
        addSwitch.on=YES;
    } else {
        addSwitch.on=NO;
    }
}

-(IBAction)toggleSwitch1:(id)sender 
{
    NSUserDefaults *userdefault=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    if (addSwitch.on) {
        [self performSelector:@selector(addName:) withObject:userName];
        NSLog(@"%@",userName);
        [userdefault setBool:YES forKey:@"yes"];
    } else {
        [userdefault setBool:NO forKey:@"no"];
        NSLog(@"No");
    }
}

-(void)addName:(UIControl*)sender 
{
    [alertList addObject:sender];
    NSLog(@"AlertList: %@", alertList);
}
```

Comment: thank you for your reply, but I'm getting an error at [self performSelector:@selector(addName:userName)]; Error: Expected ':' or ')' token.

Comment: can you tell me whats in user name it is a string or else..?

Comment: yes, that is a string, it calling the action but the string value is not adding into the array.

Comment: u can use  [alertList addObject:sender]; in add name method

Comment: I'm sorry, it is still not working, the problem is the string is not adding into the array..!!! Calling action is fine.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3882/discussion-between-mithun-and-userar)

Comment: -(void)addName:(NSString*)sender

Answer (score 3):

Looks like the issue you're having is that the toggleSwitch method is called when the state changes and then it starts listening for the change using the addTarget: method. You should choose one or the other to handle the change.

```
-(IBAction)toggleSwitch1:(id)sender{
    if (addSwitch.on) {
        [self addName:userName];
    } else {
        //do something else
    }
}

-(void)addName:(UIControl*)sender{
    [alertList addObject:userName];
}
```

To save the switch state just have another variable that stores the switch state and call the setOn:animated: method in viewDidLoad.